# How to change searchbar's scope colors?

Tags: ios, swift, scope, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

Swift 3, I'm trying to change the search bars text color from blue to black. For example the "cancel" and the scope bars blue text and border color is blue, I want it black.

This is what I have.

[image: pic1]

And I tried this line but I don't know enough and this line doesnt work as you can see.

```
searchController.searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

[image: pic2]

viewDidLoad

```
// Search Bar
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
myTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

// Search Bar Border
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

// Scope Bar
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Released", "Unreleased", "Open Beta"]
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

rest of searchBar code

```
// SEARCH BAR: Filtering Content
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

    filteredFollowedArray = followedArray.filter { Blog in

        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (Blog.blogType == scope)

        return categoryMatch && (Blog.blogName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
    }

    filteredBlogArray = blogArray.filter { Blog in

        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (Blog.blogType == scope)

        return categoryMatch && (Blog.blogName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}

// SEARCH BAR: Updating Results
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {}

// SEARCH BAR: Scope
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {

    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
}

// SEARCH BAR: Updating Scope
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]

    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
}

// Deallocating Search Bar
deinit{
    if let superView = searchController.view.superview {
        superView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

new code:

```
// Search Bar
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

// Coloring SearchBar Cancel button
let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)

 // Scope: Selected text
 let titleTextAttributesSelected = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesSelected, for: .selected)

 // Scope: Normal text
 let titleTextAttributesNormal = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesNormal, for: .normal)
```

But the scope bar is still blue and it needs to be black

[image: pic3]

updated picture
[image: pic4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re missing a few things, here is the way to do it for your search bar:

```
let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary =[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

And for your segmented control:

```
// Selected text
let titleTextAttributesSelected = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesSelected, for: .selected)

// Normal text
let titleTextAttributesNormal = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesNormal, for: .normal)
```

Comment: this worked for the cancel button but not the scope bar, it's still blue

Comment: @BroSimple, check the update to see how to change the text color of your segmented control.

Comment: thank you! but now just the text in the scope bar buttons changed, there is still blue in the border of the scope and the selected text still has the blue, (in the pic i have the "All" that has the blue background in the selected text)

Comment: Just change the tint color of your segmented control to change the borders and background. `segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor...`

Comment: It didn't, my code added the searchBar and scope bar programmatically so I can't access the color from what you told me. I updated my question with the code and picture.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @BroSimple, try this row `UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green`

Comment: This actually worked except for the fact that the background of the searchBar is now black but when you click on it, it disappears and you don't see it again. I added a picture. Why is this? It's only happening when the view first loads.

Comment: That´s weird, try `UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: still there, don't understand how it disappears when you click the searchBar and the scope bars shows, the black disappears and doesnt show up until the view loads again.

Comment: Try to set it´s background color to white and see if it makes any changes.

Comment: Try to remove `searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()`

Comment: that worked but there is a tiny grey line on top of the search bar for the border and when you click on it, the black border shows up

Comment: Okey, I´m not really sure why this happens. Anyhow, `UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green` makes the difference for changing the color of the borders. Consider asking another questions for your other issue and maybe accepting this answer if you found is useful. Good luck @BroSimple.